# Form Label - disabled or enabled?

Tags: forms, input-fields, labels

What is the best practice when it comes to a form having disabled fields? Should we show the associated labels disabled as well?

1) If labels are also disabled then it'll give a stronger clue to the user wherein just by looking at it he/she will know the field is disabled.
2) If the labels are shown enabled and form field shown disabled then user might get an impression that the form hasn't loaded properly.

Your views?

Comment: What is your situation where you're disabling fields? How do they become enabled?

Comment: Based on a selection the fields become enabled. By default they are disabled but visible.

Comment: Yes, the labels should also be disabled. You answered your own question in 1).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest progressive disclosure on this issue. Do not disable and enable them but instead keep them hidden until the approriate selection is made in the form. Then show them the field.

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/

Comment: the choice between disabling and progressive disclosure all depends on the specific form and fields. although you might be right - I don't think we know enough about the particular scenario in the question to suggest using progressive disclosure.